# AWS error in restoring of DB instance from S3 snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

When I attempted to restore the DB snapshot from S3 which is in the gz.parquet format by default, I received an error in the Status 'Incompatible-restore'. Then in the event logs of the Incompatible-restore DB instance, it indicated that the errors occurs because of unable to extract the backup files of type GZ. Please verify that your backup files in / are in a valid format.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How was this gz.parquet file created?

Answer (score 0):

The feature 'Exporting snapshot to Amazon S3' is not purposed for backup, so you can't restore an instance from it.
Amazon has written this limitation in the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html#USER_ExportSnapshot.Limits):

> - You can't restore exported snapshot data from S3 to a new DB instance.

You need to make some tools to read parquet files and import back into your DB. In my opinion, the options in the RDS console is quite misleading.